# Do I need an SSL certificate?

Tags: cognito-forms, ssl

Do I need an SSL certificate for my website if I'm using Cognito Forms?

My media person is trying to sell me an SSL certificate as Google is going to mark HTML pages with forms as "insecure", but I'm not sure if I actually need it.

Can you clarify the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

While Cognito Forms uses SSL and transfers all data entered via SSL. Our SSL will only be for the Cognito Form when its embedded on your website.